# Caching Result Sets From Multiple Databases

Tags: database, caching

I'm writing an application where a user can combine different physical tables from different databases (e.g. Oracle and SqlServer) to create one logical or "abstract" table. The abstract tables are made from joins of the physical tables. From this abstract table, the user can query the abstract table using general SQL syntax.

For example, let's say I have 3 physical tables called `SALES`, `CUSTOMERS`, `PRODUCTS` each belonging to different databases (Oracle, SqlServer, & PostgreSql). From these physical tables I create 3 abstract tables called `CUSTOMERS_SALES`, `SALES_PRODUCTS`, and `CUSTOMERS` (unchanged from the physical table).

The `CUSTOMER_SALES` and `SALES_PRODUCTS` are simply joined together via foreign keys and primary keys.

If I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
```

Then it will simply `SELECT *` from both `CUSTOMERS` and `SALES` and join them together and return the result set created.

How can I cache the result set above, so that if I were to run `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS` it will result in a cache hit. Or if I were to run `SELECT * FROM SALES_PRODUCTS` it will result in a cache hit for `SALES` and simply query the database for `PRODUCTS` because we have `SALES` in the cache.

Another example could be running a query as in the following:

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMERID, SALESID FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
```

How can I cache the query above, so that if I were to `SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM CUSTOMERS` it will result in a cache hit.

Any hints or ideas to coming up with a strategy for this caching scenario? This would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!